# Required attribute on form not working with ajax?

Tags: html, ajax, validation, required

I have a form that uses ajax to post the form values, and seems that the it doesn't read the `required` attribute on the form input. Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

Code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#send-email").click(function () {
            var subject = $("#subject").val();
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var phone = $("#phone").val();
            var message = $("#message").val();
            var nationality = document.getElementById("nationality");
            var selNationality = nationality.options[nationality.selectedIndex].text;
            //
            $.post("mail.php", {"subject": subject, "name": name, "email": email, "phone": phone, "nationality": selNationality, "message": message, }, function () {
                console.log(subject);
                console.log(name);
                console.log(email);
                console.log(phone);
                console.log(selNationality);
                console.log(message);
                alert("Thanks for contacting us, we will be back to you as soon as possible!");
            });

        });
    });
</script>
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-row">
        <p>Subject</p>
        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" required>            
        </select>
    </div>  
    <div class="form-row">
        <p>Name</p>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>          
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <p>Nationality</p>
        <select name="nationality" id="nationality" required>
            <option value="">Select Nationality</option>            
        </select>           
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <p>Contact number</p>   
        <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone">     
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <p>Email</p>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" required>            
    </div>  
    <div class="form-row">
        <p>Message</p>  
        <textarea style="width:590px;height:100px;" id="message" name="message" cols="80" rows="12" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">

    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <input type="submit" onclick="return false;" id="send-email" value="SEND" name="send"/>     
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several things wrong here. the solution depends on your needs.

1) If you don't need an asynk call to `mail.php`, just delete the javascript stuff. When you are doing this: `<form action="mail.php" method="POST">` All your form inputs will be sent using POST to the selected action, so you dont need to use javascript.

2) If you do need asynk loading of `mail.php` you need to do several things in order to work:

- remove all attributes from the form tag: `<form>`
- remove `onclick="return false;"` from the submit button tag
- check yourself the data completion, f.ex.:

  ```
  var complete = true;
  if(subject==""||name==""||email=="") {
     complete = false;
  }  
  if(complete) {
     //send post to mail.php
  } else {
     alert("You need to fill in all the fields");
  }
  ```

Keep in mind that not all explorers support this feature: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp